# My selector is not calling the function in swift. Deleting tableViewCell programatically in iOS, swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, selector, delete-row

I have a method to delet a row in a tableview:

```
@objc func didTapDelete(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let point = sender.convert(CGPoint.zero, to: tableView)
    guard let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForRow(at: point) else {
        return
    }
    prescriptions.remove(at: indexPath.row)
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.deleteRows(at: [IndexPath(row: indexPath.row, section: 0)], with: .left)
    tableView.endUpdates()
}
```

In my cellForRowAt, im calling the button.addTarget i declared in the Customcell

```
        cell.deleteButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTapDelete(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

Here is the Button in the customCell

```
    let deleteButton: UIButton = {
    let variable = UIButton()
    variable.setTitle("Delete_Button".localized, for: .normal)
    variable.setTitleColor(Colors.red, for: .normal)
    variable.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: Metrics.Spacing.medium)
    variable.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return variable
}()
```

The method is in the View inside the viewController, but when I click on the button, even though the debugger stops at the selector.addTarget call, my didTapDelete method is not called.

Im using swift 5, viewCode.

[picture of the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WO4Cz.png)

Comment: Adding an action handler every time in `cellForRowAt` might cause issues down the line as the cell gets reused, however I don't think this is your issue. I think it could be related to delayed touches. What if in the place where you create your table view, you added `tableView.delaysContentTouches = false` - does this help you ?

Comment: Hi Shawn, thanks for your tip. Unfortunately, that doesn't worked. I think the issue is due to some communication problem, but i dont see where... Anyway, thank you very much

Comment: *"the debugger stops at the selector.addTarget call, my didTapDelete method is not called"* -- is confusing. What do you mean the debugger stops at the selector? If you put a `print("tapped")` as the first line in `didTapDelete()` does it output to the debug console?

Comment: Try moving the addTarget method to willDisplayCell.

Comment: @DonMag No, my method, didTapDelete() its not beeing called. I put a breakpoint in the add.taget and when i click, it stops there, but the didTap are not beeing called

Comment: I think it's because the tableview is recognizing the click in the cell and not the button inside the cell, but, how do i do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve with

```
cell.contentView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

The problem was because the tap its recognizing the cell click did select, not the button.

Comment: That shouldn't be needed. If that ***does*** seem to fix it, it sounds like you added your button as a subview of the **cell itself** instead of adding it as a subview of the cell's `.contentView`.

Comment: Indeed, i ad the button as a Subview of the background UIVIew. I did it because i use the background size to animate the cell whent it gets clicked

Comment: Bad idea... ***all UI elements*** added to a table view cell should be added as subviews of `.contentView`. You can run into numerous other problems if they're not.

Comment: Is the way that i found to get a animation of expansion to the cell. I will refactor this code. Thank you !!